# Is a rational polynomial fully determined by its values under integer entries?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I am working with a rational polynomial $p$ in $n$ variables $x_1,...,x_n$ and know how it behaves when I plug in integers, i.e. I know that
$$ p(z_1,...,z_n) = 0$$ whenever $z_1,...,z_n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Can I conclude that $p(x_1,...,x_n) = 0$ for all $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I tried working by induction on $n$: the number of variables. When $n=1$, we have a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that has an infinite amount of roots, which means that it has to be zero (because the amount of roots of a non-zero polynomial is bounded by its degree.

Then for the induction hypothesis, assume that all rational polynomials in $n-1$ variables with the property that plugging in all integers always yields zero, are automatically zero for all rational entries.

Now applying the induction hypothesis to $p(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0)$ yields that $p$ only has terms containing a factor of $x_n$. We can do the same for all other variables.
This means that $p$ only has terms divisible by $x_1\cdot ... \cdot x_n$.

I however now don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What can you conclude about the coefficients of p, if you input (0,0,0,...,0),(0,0,0,...,1),(0,0,0,...,1,0) etc.?

Comment: @watertrainer, I edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think doing it with mathematical induction on the number of variables $n$ is a good idea. Also, rationality of the coeffecients isn't necessary, maybe there is another way that explicitely exploits that, but the statement is true assuming just real or even complex coefficients.

The inductions start with $n=1$ is easy, a non-zero polynomial of one variable of degree $m$ can have at most $m$ different roots, and since there are infinitely many integers, the polynomial must be identical to $0$.

So how to do the missing (from OP's post) induction step ($n-1 \to n$)?

We take  $x_n$ and write $p$ as a polynomial in $x_n$, where the coefficients aren't constants but polynomials in the remaining $n-1$ variables:

$$p(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = p_m(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})x_n^m + p_{m-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})x_n^{m-1}+\ldots +  p_2(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})x_n^2 + p_1(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})x_n + p_0(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}) = \sum_{i=0}^m p_i(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})x_n^i,$$

where $m$ is the highest degree that $x_n$ occurs in $p$.

Note that this works even if $p$ doesn't really depend on $x_n$, then $m=0$ and the following arguments still works on $p_0$ alone.

If all of the $p_i(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}), i=0,1,\ldots,m$ are the zero polynomial, we are done. If not, then we have a $k$ such that $p_k(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ is not identical to $0$. From the induction hypothesis we now know that there exist integers $x_1^*, \ldots, x_{n-1}^*$ such that $p_k(x_1^*,\ldots,x_{n-1}^*) \neq 0$.

That means the polynomial

$$q(x_n)=p(x_1^*,\ldots,x_{n-1}^*,x_n) = \sum_{i=0}^m p_i(x_1^*,\ldots,x_{n-1}^*)x_n^i$$

is not identical to $0$, at least the term $p_k(x_1^*,\ldots,x_{n-1}^*)x_n^k$ is not zero. But know we are back at the induction start $n=1$: We have a non-zero polynomial $q$ in one variable, so there must be some integer $x_n^*$ such that $q(x_n) \neq 0$ and that finally means $p(x_1^*,\ldots,x_{n-1}^*,x_n^*) \neq 0$.

That concludes the induction step, we have proved that any non-zero polynomial in $n$ variables cannot have roots at every point in $\mathbb Z^n$.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if a polynomial in $p\in \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ evaluates to $0$ with every tuple of integers, then does it over every tuple of rationals. The answer is yes. To see this let $a_1,\dots ,a_n$ be rational numbers, and let $b_1,\dots ,b_n$ be their respective denominators. Assume $p$ is of degree $m$. If we multiply $p$ by a constant, its roots wont change so we can multiply it by $b_1^m \times \cdots \times b_n^m$. This will not affect the roots of our polynomial, but it will have the effect removing all fraction, thus it becomes equivalent to evaluation over (different) integers, which by assumption are all roots, and thus our $a_1,\dots ,a_n$ will be roots as well.

Comment: I don't see how this works. For example, let $p$ be of the form $p(x,y) = ax^2+by^2+cxy+ dx + ey + f$ and assume that every couple of integers is a root of $p$. We want to show that f.e. $(1/2,1/3)$ is a root of $p$. So because $p$ is of degree 2, you would say that $p$ being zero is equivalent to $4\cdot 9 \cdot p$ being zero in this point. Yet I don't see how we can write $36\cdot p(1/2,1/3)$ as an evaluation of $p$ in a couple of integers.

Comment: @noparadise, $f=0$

Comment: I was originally thinking along the same lines as you, August, but I believe @noparadise is right. After multiplying by your constant term, you aren't guaranteed to have a single constant multiplier of p(x'_1,...,x'_n) for some tuple (x'_1,...,x'_n), because each individual term of the polynomial will end up with a different constant factor depending on how much of the constant multiplier was cancelled. In the specific example they give, for example, you'd end up with coefficients of 9a, 4b, 6c, etc., giving a different polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

### The concise proof

Barred letters will represent tuples of variables or numbers, e.g. $\bar{a} = (a_1, \ldots, a_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^k$. We take the following well known fact as granted:

> **Fact.** If a univariate polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients has infinitely many zeros, then it is the zero polynomial, i.e. all its coefficients are zero.

We prove by induction on $n$ that for every polynomial $p(\bar{x})$ in $n$ variables, if $p(\bar{a}) = 0$ for all $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, then $p = 0$. The case $n = 0$ is easy, since a polynomial in zero variables is a constant, and the assumption $p() = 0$ means that the constant is zero.

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and assume the statement holds for $n$. To prove it holds for $n+1$, take any polynomial $p(\bar{x}, y)$ in $n+1$ variables such that $p(\bar{a}, b) = 0$ for all $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. It can be written as

$$p(\bar{x}, y) = \sum_{i=0}^m p_i(\bar{x}) \cdot y^i$$

for some polynomials $p_0(\bar{x}), \ldots, p_m(\bar{x})$. Given any $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, the polynomial $p(\bar{a}, y)$ in the single variable $y$ evaluates to zero at every integer, so by the cited fact its coefficients are zero, i.e. $p_i(\bar{a}) = 0$ for $i = 0, \ldots, m$. By induction, $p_i$ are the zero polynomials, hence $p$ is zero as well.